# index out of range at ..\aten\src\TH/generic/THTensorEvenMoreMath.cpp:193

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to build junction tree vae.I got struck over this error.My embedding size is same as the vocabulary size and and the other parameter is hidden size length.Where am I going wrong?Please help someone.

I have read many blogs and tried solving this error but I can't.I know there is some problem with embedding but I don't know how to solve?

```
def __init__(self, vocab, hidden_size, latent_size, depthT, depthG):
        super(JTNNVAE, self).__init__()
        self.vocab = vocab
        #print(int(vocab.size()))
        self.hidden_size = int(hidden_size)
        self.latent_size = latent_size = latent_size / 2 #Tree and Mol has two vectors
        self.latent_size=int(self.latent_size)
        self.jtnn = JTNNEncoder(hidden_size, depthT, nn.Embedding(int(vocab.size()), int(hidden_size)))
        self.decoder = JTNNDecoder(vocab, hidden_size, latent_size, nn.Embedding(int(vocab.size()), int(hidden_size)))

        self.jtmpn = JTMPN(hidden_size, depthG)
        self.mpn = MPN(hidden_size, depthG)

        self.A_assm = nn.Linear(int(latent_size), int(hidden_size), bias=False)
        self.assm_loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(size_average=False)

        self.T_mean = nn.Linear(int(hidden_size), int(latent_size))
        self.T_var = nn.Linear(int(hidden_size), int(latent_size))
        self.G_mean = nn.Linear(int(hidden_size), int(latent_size))
        self.G_var = nn.Linear(int(hidden_size), int(latent_size))
```

Expected to solve this error.

Thanks.